# Right Float and container div

Tags: image, html, alignment, containers, nested

I have 3 divs in a container div. The first is floated left, the second is floated right and the last sits in the center. This creates 3 approximately even divs across a container div.

In each of these divs I am placing an image of varying heights. Then there is a separate div to sit below the container div which will be the full width (call it description div).

I want the container div to stretch to height of largest image div so that the description div sits nicely underneath the images. Currently this works when the left floated and middle divs contain the largest image but not for the right floated div. I cannot see why or what i'm missing any help would be much appreciated.

NOTE: I'm trying to do this without using any absolute values, just percentages. So I don't want to declare an absolute height to the container div! Also clear's will not work as this is simplified and there are actually a lot of other div containers around all of this etc, unless you can clear just the floats in the above nested div.

Here's the code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        #b_pics {
            border: 2px solid grey;
            width: 100%;
        }
        #b_pic1 {
            border: 0px solid grey;
            float:left;
            width:33%;
        }
        #b_pic2 {
            border: 0px solid grey;
            margin: 0px auto;
            width: 33%
        }
        #b_pic3 {
            border: 0px solid grey;
            float:right;
            width:33%;
        }
        #b_website {
            border: 1px solid grey;
            width:100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='b_pics'>
        <div id='b_pic1'>
            Image 1 here    
        </div>
        <div id='b_pic3'>
            Image 3 here            
        </div>
        <div id='b_pic2'>
            Image 2 here                    
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id='b_website'>
        Line of text goes here
    </div>
</body>
```

Thanks in advance for any help, trying to keep any hair thats left in my head!

Comment: Looks like someone's been on a downvoting spree and downvoted the question and all the answers. Weird.

Answer (score 1):

A containing element won't stretch to accommodate floating divs. In your example, the the containing div has no actual content and will thus be 0 pixels high. Try changing the border or background colour to illustrate this.

You can force an element to be below any floating divs by giving it the style:

```
clear: both;
```

You can also clear just left or right floating divs.

You can add an empty div after your three picture divs that has that style, to make the b_pics container stretch to accommodate the floating elements, or you could just make the b_website div clear both.

Comment: thanks for the comments, I'm trying to make them work seems i'm very close. I'll post more detailed code if i continue to have trouble. THnaks

Answer (score 0):

I totally agree with SpoonMeiser answer. I had the same problem (only with IE do) and adding a clear: both (div in my case) is the only solution that seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

SpoonMeiser's explanation is correct. Here is some code that should work for you. Essentially, I've added an empty div with "clear:both" at the end of your container div. This forces the container to take up the space of the floating divs it contains.

This is better than making the #b_website div "clear:both" (SpoonMeiser's alternative suggestion) because that would make the #b_website div display in the correct place but would not force the #b_pics border to surround the floating divs.

```
<div id='b_pics'>
    <div id='b_pic1'>
        Image 1 here</div>
    <div id='b_pic3'>
        Image 3 here
    </div>
    <div id='b_pic2'>
        Image 2 here
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
<div id='b_website'>
    Line of text goes here
</div>
```

I hope that helps?

Answer (score -1):

Give [this](http://www.manisheriar.com/holygrail/rightcol.htm) a shot. Nothing's hard-coded, and it should do what you want.